Forgetting my work skill and experience
I have worked 8 years as software developer in IT industry. Due to personal reasons I had to move to a new country where I am pursuing Master in computer science. The course is not offering me much and I have to wait for atleast one more year before I can start work. I feel like I am forgetting everything I learnt in office. Everyday I am losing confidence. How can I overcome this?
Editing : I am already refreshing my skill , but some work can be done in the production server at a big level, I feel like I am forgetting this kind of skill

Remember that software development is mostly a "learning skill", not a specific knowledge use skill. Every system is different. Every job environment is different. Things change year by year (or day by day) and we have to be constantly learning. You won't have forgotten how to learn in one year.

I don't think you can completely forget the skills you learnt for 8 years.
Most companies won't worry that you may forget your skills you learnt in 8 years.
When you go back to school to earn a higher degree, it is not considered a gap in your employment history, knowledge or skills.


How can I overcome this?

You only need to spend some time to refresh your skills, and you will quickly remember them.
For example, if you worked as a software developer, then to refresh your coding skills, you can try to complete 100 Leetcode style coding problems. That should get you up to the speed very quickly.
If you want to refresh your skills with Jira, Git, database, etc... then you can easily try these software on your own time. They are very simple as you already know.

Thankyou so much !
